# Which package should I choose if I want to install virtualenv for python?

Tags: debian, python, pip

pip search just returns too many matches amd I am confused about which package I should choose to install.

Should I only install `virtualenv`?  Or I'd better also install `virtualenv-commands` and `virtualenv-commands` etc. but I really don't know exactly what virtualenv-commands is.

```
mirror0@lab:~$ pip search virtualenv


virtualenvwrapper         - Enhancements to virtualenv
virtualenv                - Virtual Python Environment builder
veh                       - virtualenv for hg
pyutilib.virtualenv       - PyUtilib utility for building custom virtualenv bootstrap scripts.
envbuilder                - A package for automatic generation of virtualenvs
virtstrap-core            - A bootstrapping mechanism for virtualenv+pip and shell scripts
tox                       - virtualenv-based automation of test activities
virtualenvwrapper-win     - Port of Doug Hellmann's virtualenvwrapper to Windows batch scripts
everyapp.bootstrap        - Enhanced virtualenv bootstrap script creation.
orb                       - pip/virtualenv shell script wrapper
monupco-virtualenv-python - monupco.com registration agent for stand-alone Python virtualenv applications
virtualenvwrapper-powershell - Enhancements to virtualenv (for Windows). A clone of Doug Hellmann's virtualenvwrapper
RVirtualEnv               - relocatable python virtual environment
virtualenv-clone          - script to clone virtualenvs.
virtualenvcontext         - switch virtualenvs with a python context manager
lessrb                    - Wrapper for ruby less so that it's in a virtualenv.
carton                    - make self-extracting virtualenvs
virtualenv5               - Virtual Python 3 Environment builder
clever-alexis             - Clever redhead girl that builds and packs Python project with Virtualenv into rpm, deb, etc.
kforgeinstall             - Virtualenv bootstrap script for KForge
pypyenv                   - Install PyPy in virtualenv
virtualenv-distribute     - Virtual Python Environment builder
virtualenvwrapper.project - virtualenvwrapper plugin to manage a project work directory
virtualenv-commands       - Additional commands for virtualenv.
rjm.recipe.venv           - zc.buildout recipe to turn the entire buildout tree into a virtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.bitbucket - virtualenvwrapper plugin to manage a project work directory based on a BitBucket repository
tg_bootstrap              - Bootstrap a TurboGears app in a VirtualEnv
django-env                - Automaticly manages virtualenv for django project
virtual-node              - Install node.js into your virtualenv
django-environment        - A plugin for virtualenvwrapper that makes setting up and creating new Django environments easier.
vip                       - vip is a simple library that makes your python aware of existing virtualenv underneath.
virtualenvwrapper.django  - virtualenvwrapper plugin to create a Django project work directory
terrarium                 - Package and ship relocatable python virtualenvs
venv_dependencies         - Easy to install any dependencies in a virtualenviroment(without making symlinks by hand and etc...)
virtualenv-sh             - Convenient shell interface to virtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.github  - Plugin for virtualenvwrapper to automatically create projects based on github repositories.
virtualenvwrapper.configvar - Plugin for virtualenvwrapper to automatically export config vars found in your project level .env file.
virtualenvwrapper-emacs-desktop - virtualenvwrapper plugin to control emacs desktop mode
bootstrapper              - Bootstrap Python projects with virtualenv and pip.
virtualenv3               - Obsolete fork of virtualenv
isotoma.depends.zope2_13_8 - Running zope in a virtualenv
virtual-less              - Install lessc into your virtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.tmpenv  - Temporary virtualenvs are automatically deleted when deactivated
isotoma.plone.heroku      - Tooling for running Plone on heroku in a virtualenv
gae-virtualenv            - Using virtualenv with zipimport on Google App Engine
pinvenv                   - VirtualEnv plugins for pin
isotoma.depends.plone4_1  - Running plone in a virtualenv
virtualenv-tools          - A set of tools for virtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.npm     - Plugin for virtualenvwrapper to automatically encapsulate inside the virtual environment any npm installed globaly when the venv is activated
d51.django.virtualenv.test_runner - Simple package for running isolated Django tests from within virtualenv
difio-virtualenv-python   - Difio registration agent for stand-alone Python virtualenv applications
VirtualEnvManager         - A package to manage various virtual environments.
virtualenvwrapper.gem     - Plugin for virtualenvwrapper to automatically encapsulate inside the virtual environment any gems installed when the venv is activated
```

Answer (score 2):

Package management is meant to make your life easier, not harder. The simplest answer is usually correct - virtualenv.

If this package depends upon another, both should be installed. That's the **point** of a package manager.

Comment: the implementation of pip is interesting, but if you want to know more, maybe you should read the source code of python:( that is hell of details, but details are so attractive:)

Comment: I find the implementation of most Python things "interesting". It never seems to follow the logical route I'd have expected it to. But usually common sense prevails in some element of its design... :P

Comment: how do you stduy the details of how python language is implemented? it is interesting:) but a bit difficult...